# ERROR: x86 HAX kernel module is not installed! But it is installed

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

This is a problem that I've researched and googled but have not found any answers for that I haven't already tried. I'm using android studio kit to learn how to develop android application but I can't get pass launching the avd emulator. I set the path for the sdk in environment variables like this:[image]

Here is a screenshot of where I installed intel HAXM in the sdk.
[image]

Here is the error message:
[image]

Can somebody out there give me some advise on how to solve this problem. Thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK Manager only downloads HAXM. It does not actually install it. For Windows, in the `extras\` directory in your SDK installation, you should find an `intel\` directory. Drill down inside of there to find a self-installing `.EXE` file. Run that and follow the prompts in the wizard. Note that you may need to reboot to update your BIOS settings to enable virtualization extensions.

See also [this outstanding Android tools issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81798).

Comment: What do I do if I don't see the intel\directory? I found the extras directory and at the end of that directory is intel x86Emulator Accellerator (HAXM installer) that is checked installed. Should I uninstall everything and reinstall Android Studio? I'm puzzled.

Comment: @swydell: Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29), "In computing, a directory is a file system cataloging structure which contains references to other computer files, and possibly other directories." The "`extras` directory in your SDK installation" refers to a spot, probably on your `C:` drive, that contains files and directories. The "SDK installation" refers to the directory where your Android SDK is located (the SDK Manager will show you this as "SDK Path"). There is an `extras` directory inside of there, and an `intel` directory inside of `extras`, etc.

Comment: I am now using the emulator. I thank you so much for your advise and patience. This has been a learning experience. I now understand better what I'm doing. I went to my C drive where my android is located and found the extras folder and then the intel folder, right-clicked on the intelham-android application, ran it as administrator. I  hope these instructions will help someone else that experience the same problem. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you chose a different location from Google's recommended one when installing the SDK, the path to Intel HAX installer should be `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` which you can open via Windows Run. Then the following explorer window opens:
[image]
Click and run `intelhaxm-android.exe` installer.
[image]
In the next window, leave RAM share for the emulator on the default 1024 MB. Continue and finish the installation.
[image]
Run your application in Android Studio and select your emulator (Here, Nexus 5 API 21 X86).
[image]
The emulator runs as follows:
[image]