# AVD still not running even after enabling the VT-x in virtualization technology

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, bios, haxm

1) I found this error in Android Studio

[image: android studio error message]

2) And then I followed the instructions given here 
[ERROR: x86 HAX kernel module is not installed! But it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726367/error-x86-hax-kernel-module-is-not-installed-but-it-is-installed)

3) So, I checked my BIOS settings and found this

[image: BIOS advanced system settings]

4) And then launched the file "intelhaxm-android.exe" located in "C:\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager"
 and during the installation, I got this error message

[image: error msg during the installation]

- Recently I formatted my pc and before formatting, there weren't any errors like these. AVD started pretty well. What should I do to get rid of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd/26380900#26380900

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to resolve this problem!

1) First, you need to change VT-x in to **disable** mode  in Virtualization Technology in BIOS settings
2) Go 'Save and Exit' and your PC will restart

**IMPORTANT**

3) When you come to the logging screen do not logged in!
4) Go 'Switch user' and **shutdown** your PC (not **restart**)
5) Start your PC and go to BIOS settings and now you need to set Virtualiazation Technology to VT-x mode
6) And then repeat 2nd, 3rd and 4th steps again

- You may need to install "intelhaxm-android.exe" located in your sdk directory
- In my case, I didn't want to install "intelhaxm-android.exe"
- Now I'm using [genymotin](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)